# Modal no aparece, solo se oscurece la pantalla

Tags: javascript, php, modal

Necesito que aparezca un modal donde se elimina un registro, pero solamente se oscurece la pantalla al dar clic en el botón.
Al inspeccionar la paginar, no aparecen errores de ningún tipo.

Aquí esta mi llamado en JS, donde se programa el evento:

```
const eliminaModal = document.getElementById('eliminaModal')
eliminaModal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', (event) => {
  let button = event.relatedTarget
  let id = button.getAttribute('data-bs-id')
  eliminaModal.querySelector('.modal-footer #id').value = id
})
```

Aquí programo mi botón en el index:

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#eliminaModal" data-bs-id="<?= $row ['id']; ?>">
      <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>
      Borrar
</a>
```

Este es el código del modal, donde se pregunta al usuario si quiere borrar el registro y se programan los botones de cerrar, cancelar y eliminar:

```
<!-- Modal para editar un registro -->
<div class="modal fade" id="eliminaModal" tabindex="-1"
     aria-labelledby="eliminaModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="eliminaModalLabel">
                    Eliminar Registro
                </h1>
                <button class="btn-close"
                        type="button" 
                        data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close"
                >
                </button>
            </div>         
            <div class="modal-body">
                ¿Deseas eliminar el registro?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <form action="elimina.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-secondary"
                            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                    >
                        Cerrar
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit"
                            class="btn btn-danger"
                    >
                        Eliminar
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y aunque no creo que tenga algo que ver, aquí está el código que elimina el registro de la base de datos:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'config/database.php';

    $id = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $queryDelete = "DELETE FROM pelicula WHERE id=$id";
    if($conn->query($queryDelete)) {
        $_SESSION['color'] = 'success';
        $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Registro eliminado';

        $dir = 'posters';
        $poster = $dir . '/' . $id . '.jpg';
        if(file_exists($poster)) {
            unlink($poster);
        }
    } else{
        $_SESSION['color'] = 'danger';
        $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Error al eliminar el registro';
    }
    header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Comment: Yo he tenido el mismo problema ocasionalmente. No he logrado reproducirlo ni determinar qué lo causa, pero lo que ha funcionado para mi es quitar la clase *fade* del modal.

Answer (score 0):

Probé tu código con la sola modificación de cerrar una etiqueta `<div>` del modal que faltaba. Funciona tal como cabe esperar. Si acaso tu código tuviese el mismo problema de etiquetas mal cerradas eso podría explicar que no se dibuje el body, por ejemplo por quedar dentro de otro contenedor que está "más abajo" que el contenido normal.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#eliminaModal" data-bs-id="1234">
  <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i> Borrar
</a>


<!-- Modal para editar un registro -->
<div class="modal fade" id="eliminaModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="eliminaModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="eliminaModalLabel">
          Eliminar Registro
        </h1>
        <button class="btn-close" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ¿Deseas eliminar el registro?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form action="elimina.php" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                        Cerrar
                    </button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                        Eliminar
                    </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```